# TableView with SearchController - DEINIT not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, retain, uisearchcontroller

I have added a search bar and search display controller from the interface builder to my app. I am not able to get it to deinit (dealloc) properly.

It is showing the following behavior (swift2, ios9):

- User doesn't search anything, just selects an item from tableView, **DEINIT is called**
- User searches something (or just taps in the search bar), cancel the search, select item from tableView, **DEINIT is called**
- User searches something (or just taps the search bar), and selects an item from tableView, **DEINIT is NOT called** :(

The same behaviour occurs if I select "Back" in the navigation controller instead of selecting an item.

```
code removed - refer to COMPLETE CODE at bottom of post.
```

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE** Further testing has shown that removing the progressHud/loadingHud from the view controller entirely has no impact on the DEINIT not getting called. It must be something to do with the tableview or the searchcontroller itself...

**UPDATE 2** I have tried calling the searchBarCancelButtonClicked() method in my viewWillDissapear and it still doesn't release. Even though if you click "cancel" and then navigate away it does...

**UPDATE 3** Changing the willDisappear/didDisappear to the following has had no impact on the DEINIT - but does not give buggy interface issues (thanks Polina). I am trying to nil out anything I can to get a release, but no luck so far.

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchController.searchBar)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    print("View did disappear")
    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchController.active = false
    loadingHud.removeFromSuperview()
    progressHud.removeFromSuperview()
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = nil
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = nil
    searchController = nil
    tableView = nil

    super.viewDidDisappear(true)

}
```

**UPDATE 4** Still no answer I've found. Really hoping someone can help!

**UPDATE 5** In response to @ConfusedByCode - I have updated the following methods to use `[unowned self] in` inside of all closure or background thread operations:

```
code removed - refer to COMPLETE CODE at bottom of post
```

I am still not seeing DEINIT. I'm checking to make sure I didn't make a silly mistake somewhere.

**UPDATE 6** I have removed extra weak self's and made sure the closures are utilizing `[weak self] in` and unwrapping them safely. The DEINIT still is not called.

**UPDATE 7** Changed two things to no avail - made appDel `unowned let appDel`, and put searchBar.resignFirstResponder() in finishSearch(). Still not receiving deinit.

**COMPLETE CODE: (REPRESENTS UPDATE 7)**

**FOR CORRECT ANSWER SEE CODE PASTED UNDER CORRECTED CODE**

```
class AirportSearchTBVC: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
var airportData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var filteredData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var searchController: UISearchController!
unowned let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var progressHud: ProgressHUD!
var loadingHud: ProgressHUD!
var arrDepOfFlight: String!
var dateOfFlight: NSDate!
var tailNum: String!
var selectedAirportIdent: String!

deinit {
    print("TBVC Dealloc")

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    progressHud = ProgressHUD(text: "Searching")
    loadingHud = ProgressHUD(text: "Loading")
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(loadingHud)

    appDel.backgroundThread(background: { [weak self] in
        if let weakSelf = self {
            let airportHelper = AirportHelper()
            weakSelf.airportData = airportHelper.getAirportSearchData()
        }
        },
        completion: {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in
                if let weakSelf = self {
                    if weakSelf.isVisible && weakSelf.isTopViewController {
                        weakSelf.filteredData = (weakSelf.airportData)
                        weakSelf.loadingHud.removeFromSuperview()
                        weakSelf.updateSearchResultsForSearchController(weakSelf.searchController)
                        weakSelf.tableView.reloadData()

                    }

                }
            }
    });

}

//MARK: Searchbar methods (All background thread methods are in here)
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    filteredData = airportData
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if isVisible && isTopViewController {
        if let startCount = searchController.searchBar.text?.length {
            if searchController.searchBar.text!.length >= 3 && searchController.searchBar.text!.length == startCount{
                view.addSubview(progressHud)
                finishSearch()
            }
        }
    }
}
func finishSearch () {
    appDel.backgroundThread(background: { [weak self] in
        if let weakSelf = self {
            if weakSelf.isVisible && weakSelf.isTopViewController {
                let searchText = weakSelf.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString

                weakSelf.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
                weakSelf.filteredData = weakSelf.airportData.filter{
                    if let ident = $0["ident"] {
                        if ident.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    if let name  = $0["name"] {
                        if name.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    if let city = $0["municipality"] {
                        if city.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        },
        completion: {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in

                if let weakSelf = self {
                    if weakSelf.isVisible && weakSelf.isTopViewController {
                        weakSelf.tableView.reloadData()
                        weakSelf.progressHud.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
                }
            }
    });
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if isVisible && isTopViewController {
        if let startCount = searchController.searchBar.text?.length {
            if searchController.searchBar.text!.length >= 3 && searchController.searchBar.text!.length == startCount{
                view.addSubview(progressHud)
                finishSearch()
            }
        }
    }
}


//MARK: Table view methods:
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows



    if searchController.active {
        return filteredData.count
    } else {
        return airportData.count
    }


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: AirportSearchTableViewCell
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AirportSearchTableViewCell
    if searchController.active {
        let airportDict = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        let airportIdent = airportDict["ident"]
        let airportName = airportDict["name"]
        let airportRegion = airportDict["iso_region"]
        let airportCity = airportDict["municipality"]
        cell.loadItem(airportIdent, name: airportName, region: airportRegion, city: airportCity)
    } else {
        let airportDict = airportData[indexPath.row]
        let airportIdent = airportDict["ident"]
        let airportName = airportDict["name"]
        let airportRegion = airportDict["iso_region"]
        let airportCity = airportDict["municipality"]
        cell.loadItem(airportIdent, name: airportName, region: airportRegion, city: airportCity)
    }
    return cell
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchController.searchBar)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    print("View did disappear")
    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchController.active = false
    searchController.delegate = nil
    searchController.resignFirstResponder()
    loadingHud.removeFromSuperview()
    progressHud.removeFromSuperview()
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = nil
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = nil
    searchController.removeFromParentViewController()
    searchController = nil
    tableView = nil
    super.viewDidDisappear(true)

}

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}



// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AirportSearchTableViewCell
    selectedAirportIdent = cell.identLbl.text!
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("searchMapVC", sender: nil)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "searchMapVC" {
        let mapVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SearchMapController
        mapVC.arrDepOfFlight = arrDepOfFlight
        mapVC.dateOfFlight = dateOfFlight
        mapVC.tailNum = tailNum
        mapVC.selectedAirportIdent = selectedAirportIdent
    }
}
}
//MARK: EXTENSIONS
extension String {
    var length: Int { return characters.count    }  // Swift 2.0
}
extension UIViewController {
    public var isVisible: Bool {
        if isViewLoaded() {
            return view.window != nil
        }
        return false
}

public var isTopViewController: Bool {
        if self.navigationController != nil {
            return self.navigationController?.visibleViewController === self
        } else if self.tabBarController != nil {
            return self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController == self && self.presentedViewController == nil
        } else {
            return self.presentedViewController == nil && self.isVisible
        }
    }

}
```

**CORRECTED CODE [FIXED]** As Mikael Hellman suggested, there is some sort of retain bug occurring with definesPresentationContext which was originally in my viewWillAppear method. I have removed that line and done some slight massaging of my code. It is now working perfectly.

Thank you so much for the effort and the answer! Also, thank you to @confusedByCode for the help - I am sure his suggestions were a component of my problem as well, but didn't end up being the final answer.

```
import UIKit

class AirportSearchTBVC: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
var airportData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var filteredData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var searchController: UISearchController!
let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var progressHud: ProgressHUD!
var loadingHud: ProgressHUD!
var arrDepOfFlight: String!
var dateOfFlight: NSDate!
var tailNum: String!
var selectedAirportIdent: String!

deinit {
    print("TBVC Dealloc")

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    progressHud = ProgressHUD(text: "Searching")
    loadingHud = ProgressHUD(text: "Loading")
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    //definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(loadingHud)

    appDel.backgroundThread(background: { [weak self] in
        if let weakSelf = self {
            let airportHelper = AirportHelper()
            weakSelf.airportData = airportHelper.getAirportSearchData()
        }
        },
        completion: {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in
                if let weakSelf = self {
                    print("isVisible: \(weakSelf.isVisible)")
                    print("isTopViewController: \(weakSelf.isTopViewController)")
                    if weakSelf.isVisible  {
                        weakSelf.filteredData = (weakSelf.airportData)
                        weakSelf.loadingHud.removeFromSuperview()
                        weakSelf.updateSearchResultsForSearchController(weakSelf.searchController)
                        weakSelf.tableView.reloadData()
                    }


                }
            }
    });

}

//MARK: Searchbar methods (All background thread methods are in here)
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    filteredData = airportData
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        if let startCount = searchController.searchBar.text?.length {
            if searchController.searchBar.text!.length >= 3 && searchController.searchBar.text!.length == startCount{
                view.addSubview(progressHud)
                finishSearch()
            }
        }

}
func finishSearch () {
    appDel.backgroundThread(background: { [weak self] in
        if let weakSelf = self {

                let searchText = weakSelf.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString

                //weakSelf.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
                weakSelf.filteredData = weakSelf.airportData.filter{
                    if let ident = $0["ident"] {
                        if ident.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    if let name  = $0["name"] {
                        if name.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    if let city = $0["municipality"] {
                        if city.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                }

        }
        },
        completion: {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in

                if self.isVisible {

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.progressHud.removeFromSuperview()
                }



            }
    });
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        if let startCount = searchController.searchBar.text?.length {
            if searchController.searchBar.text!.length >= 3 && searchController.searchBar.text!.length == startCount{
                view.addSubview(progressHud)
                finishSearch()
            }
        }

}


//MARK: Table view methods:
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows



    if searchController.active {
        return filteredData.count
    } else {
        return airportData.count
    }


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: AirportSearchTableViewCell
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AirportSearchTableViewCell
    if searchController.active {
        let airportDict = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        let airportIdent = airportDict["ident"]
        let airportName = airportDict["name"]
        let airportRegion = airportDict["iso_region"]
        let airportCity = airportDict["municipality"]
        cell.loadItem(airportIdent, name: airportName, region: airportRegion, city: airportCity)
    } else {
        let airportDict = airportData[indexPath.row]
        let airportIdent = airportDict["ident"]
        let airportName = airportDict["name"]
        let airportRegion = airportDict["iso_region"]
        let airportCity = airportDict["municipality"]
        cell.loadItem(airportIdent, name: airportName, region: airportRegion, city: airportCity)
    }
    return cell
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    searchController.active = false
    loadingHud.removeFromSuperview()
    progressHud.removeFromSuperview()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    print("View did disappear")


    super.viewDidDisappear(true)

}

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}



// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AirportSearchTableViewCell
    selectedAirportIdent = cell.identLbl.text!
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("searchMapVC", sender: nil)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "searchMapVC" {
        let mapVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SearchMapController
        mapVC.arrDepOfFlight = arrDepOfFlight
        mapVC.dateOfFlight = dateOfFlight
        mapVC.tailNum = tailNum
        mapVC.selectedAirportIdent = selectedAirportIdent
    }
}
}
//MARK: EXTENSIONS
extension String {
    var length: Int { return characters.count    }  // Swift 2.0
}
extension UIViewController {
    public var isVisible: Bool {
        if isViewLoaded() {
            return view.window != nil
        }
        return false
}

public var isTopViewController: Bool {
        if self.navigationController != nil {
            return self.navigationController?.visibleViewController === self
        } else if self.tabBarController != nil {
            return self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController == self && self.presentedViewController == nil
        } else {
            return self.presentedViewController == nil && self.isVisible
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have pin pointed the error, but I am not close to an solution... When you focus the search, the deinit will not kick. I think this is because there is some Apple magic that is automatically triggering an animation (follow the superviews and you will find a Apple owned UITransitionView). I believe it is this transition that retains the controller... But I have found no way to nil it out, or prevent this transition from happening.... :(

Comment: At least you are close! I sure am not - I feel like I've tried everything and it is getting very depressing :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleted my old answer, found the problem.

Remove:

```
definesPresentationContext = true // Remove this line...
```

Read about it here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/definesPresentationContext

---

There must a bug in UISearchController. Some Apple code must be retaining your controller.

Maybe the transition view (animation) is not completed when the controller is unlinked (it has special toView and fromView etc, that we can not reach), and this prevents the controller from being deallocated.

I think you should file this as a bug with Apple.

---

Also I would recommend changing your deinit to:

```
deinit {
  print("TBVC Dealloc")
  if let superView = searchController.view.superview
  {
    superView.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

This will ensure the search controller is never trying to present stuff when getting deallocated, as this creates warnings and potential unexpected behavior.

Comment: This is really exciting - I will give it a try as soon as I can and report back!

Comment: You, sir, are the man. I would never in a million years have found that. Thank you so much for the effort, and please enjoy the bounty!

Comment: @Charlie Thank you! Glad to be of help.

Comment: Setting `definesPresentationContext` to `true` is sometimes required depending on the context of your searchbar.  For example, if your UITableView is pushed onto a UINavigationController then it's usually desired to set `definesPresentationContext` to true.  Otherwise, the search bar gets presented from the navigation controller and causes probems when pushing and popping controllers.  So while this may seem to solve the problem, it doesn't handle every use case.

Comment: @chris is right. For anyone who is stuck, apart from not setting definesPresentationContext to true you would want to hide your searchBar in viewWillDisappear and and make it reappear in viewWillAppear. This won't add the searchBar to other viewControllers.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue today as well
this line of code seems to work to get your class released

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    searchController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
  }
```

Here is my sample project on dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzs0m4n9maxd2u5/TestSearch.zip?dl=0

Comment: No need to set `definesPresentationContext ` to `false` anymore. This is the correct way of handling it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are creating strong reference cycles between your closures and self, because you are using an unwrapped weak self in the closures.

For example, this:

```
if let safeSelf = weakSelf {
    appDel.backgroundThread(background: {
            let airportHelper = AirportHelper()
            safeSelf.airportData = airportHelper.getAirportSearchData()
        },
        completion: {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if safeSelf.isVisible && safeSelf.isTopViewController {
                    safeSelf.filteredData = (safeSelf.airportData)
                    safeSelf.loadingHud.removeFromSuperview()
                    safeSelf.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Should be:

```
appDel.backgroundThread(background: { [weak self] in
        let airportHelper = AirportHelper()
        self?.airportData = airportHelper.getAirportSearchData()
    },
    completion: {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in
            if self?.isVisible && safeSelf.isTopViewController {
                self?.filteredData = (safeSelf.airportData)
                self?.loadingHud.removeFromSuperview()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
});
```

You can also use `[unowned self]` and you won't have to treat them as optional, but to be honest, I forget the pros and cons of unowned vs. weak. But I'm confident that if you declare the `weak self` or `unowned self` in a capture list in the closure, rather than outside of the closure and unwrapping it, your object will be properly deinitialized.

Comment: I am trying this now - with [unowned self] to try and avoid some confusing unwrapped errors that I'm afraid might cause a retain. Thanks for the post will report what happens!

Comment: I have added Update 5 to my question, could you please review the update and indicate what I've done wrong? I have tried to apply your answer with negative results.

Comment: I just noticed that you were able to deinit the vc when you set the searchController and tableView to nil. It could be because you're creating a local variable for `weak self` and setting it as the resultsUpdater and searchController delegate. The docs say searchControllers automatically set searchResultsUpdater as weak, so you don't need to do it yourself. Try getting rid all the extra `weak self`s you're making, and set the searchResultsUpdater and delegate directly to self. You only really need weak self in the capture lists of the closures. I think they might be doing more harm than good.

Comment: I believe I've removed all of the offending weak self extras. Please see Update 6 - still not deallocating. I tried to simplify as much as possible the methods that use background threads to make it easier. I truly appreciate your help more than you can imagine!

Comment: Wow, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. The last thing I noticed is that you could try calling `searchBar.resignFirstReponder()` in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` and `updateSearchResultsForSeachController`. If that doesn't work, you might need to call `resignFirstResponder` in one of the closures of your `finishSearch` method instead, because it's performed asynchronously. Aside from that, I'm out of ideas Sorry!

Comment: I think I've done what you described, but it doesn't look like it worked :( Thanks for your help thus far - idk what I'd be doing without these ideas. I'm not sure if I missed any places you thought I'd have changed, though.