# self.definesPresentationContext = true: leads to black screen?

Tags: ios, swift, screen, uisearchcontroller, searchbar

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

  //  searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

When the search bar is active, with text in it, and I go to another tab and then back, the controller is black, apart from the actual search bar. Things go back to normal when I cancel and empty the search text field.
My question is basically identical to this question: [UISearchController causes black screen Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291347/uisearchcontroller-causes-black-screen-swift-2-0)

Except that that answer does not solve my problem as you can see. What does solve it is if I change self to searchController, thus: searchController.definesPresentationContext = true. But this results in the search bar appearing in the next controller I tab to. Very confused, please help.

I am using a tableview embedded in a navigation controller and tab bar controller. viewDidDisappear is not being called when the search is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution per se, but a workaround, this stackeroverflow post helped:
[TableView with SearchController - DEINIT not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487603/tableview-with-searchcontroller-deinit-not-called). I am not sure if this is some kind of apple bug.

Apparently I am not supposed to use self.definesPresentationContext = true at all. This makes my search appear in all my tabs. But at least viewDidDisappear is called.

In viewDidDisappear, I can hide the search bar with searchController.searchBar.hidden = true and show the bar again in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score -1):

in the AppDelegate.swift

```
window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```