# black screen visible when dragging viewcontroller to tabbarcontroller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

When i am presenting from TabbarController to Outside Viewcontroller presenting correctly and also Dismiss correctly.but when i drag to dismiss the ViewController it show's Black screen using UIPanGestureRecognizer.

From TabbarController to ViewController Present Code

```
  let newVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleViewController") as! ExampleViewController
  self.definesPresentationContext = true
  newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
  self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Dismiss ExampleViewController to  TabbarController Code

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

     let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                   action: #selector(panGestureRecognizerHandler(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

}

@IBAction func panGestureRecognizerHandler(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: view?.window)
    var initialTouchPoint = CGPoint.zero

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        initialTouchPoint = touchPoint

    case .changed:
        if touchPoint.y > initialTouchPoint.y {
            view.frame.origin.y = touchPoint.y - initialTouchPoint.y

        }
    case .ended, .cancelled:
        if touchPoint.y - initialTouchPoint.y > 200 {

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                         y: 0,
                                         width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                         height: self.view.frame.size.height)

            })
        }
    case .failed, .possible:
        break
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}
```

Note:- My Project hierarchy  like this NavigationController --> SomeViewControllers -->TabbarViewController-->ExampleViewController

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share a screen-shot of your UI?

Comment: you mean ExampleViewController in my UI ?

Comment: That is not how to drag a view controller’s view. You need a custom interactive transition animation.

Comment: Remove this line: `newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext` and try again to drag.

Comment: @Niraj,i removed this line also but not working remains same.any other thing to change in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried your code, just provide the `NavigationController` between tab screen and your view controller.

```
let newVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleViewController") as! ExampleViewController
newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And in next screen used same function as you mentioned above, no black screen.

Or you can use below line in `AppDelegate` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45994837/12830762

`window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`

Comment: i am tried what u said but remain same black screen .anything i want to change in UI or code ?

Comment: When i am tried with Viewcontroller to ExampleViewController it's working fine

Comment: Actually When dismiss ViewController to ViewController Working good without black screen.but When it came to ViewController to TabbarController not working .it's showing black screen.When drag to dismiss

Comment: I Updated my UI check it

Comment: Your UI looks perfect. From where are you presenting your `ExampleViewController` tabbar or first view controller of tabbar?

Comment: i am presenting from  FirstViewController of Tabbar.When click on Button inside FirstViewController presenting Example ViewController

Comment: Then it is working good in my case. Did you removed `self.definesPresentationContext = true` ?

Comment: i removed that line but remains same black screen

Comment: This is the only thing that I found leads to showing black screen tried with my code as same hierarchy and also found in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943496/self-definespresentationcontext-true-leads-to-black-screen

Comment: i found solution window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white this line just added in AppDelegate it's working good with baground white color

Comment: Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert navigation controller in between the

TabbarViewController-->ExampleViewController

So it should be :

TabbarViewController--> NavigationController -->ExampleViewController

Just Select ExampleViewController choose Embed Navigation controller in storyboard.
And Use Segue push method.

Comment: i don't want to use Segue method.and also without NavigationController to ExampleViewController it's work good for me.

Comment: you can use present with navigation controller also and hide navigationbar if not required.

Comment: i am also tried this this let newVC : AddActivityVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleViewController") as! ExampleViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newVC)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)

Comment: but not working,i used present in place of push remains same

Comment: use like this:


let exampleViewController  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleViewController") as! ExampleViewController 


let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: exampleViewController)


 navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle. overCurrentContext


 self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)